# Bot Builder - Application Insights broken after changed Resource group on Azure

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-application-insights

I'm building a Bot using the .NET SDK, hosted on Azure. I recently added Application Insights to my application following this guide -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net

This was simple enough, however I launched App Insights using a Resource group I had insufficient permissions for. I changed resource groups and everything broke after that. I tried changing the  in 'ApplicationInsights.config' to the new key (as app insights was now on a new resource group)

[image: Image - App Insights Issue]

I attempted to remove Application insights by uninstalling the relevant NuGet packages and dependencies, but this didn't work either, so I rolled my project back to an earlier copy with my original application insights files for my application.

Basically, I need help re-configuring my Application Insight settings to connect to a new resource group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the easiest answer would have been to use the "Configure application insights" menu item from that menu?

[image: configure application insights]

which would bring up the configure window and let you pick a new resource through the UI.

that item might have gone away if you deleted things and removed packages though.

that doesn't work work, the resource it is trying to go to is in your `.csproj` file, like

```
<ApplicationInsightsResourceId>/subscriptions/[subscriptionid]/resourcegroups/[resourcegroupname]/providers/microsoft.insights/components/[appname]</ApplicationInsightsResourceId>
```

you could manually edit it to the new resource id, and manually update the instrumentation key as well.  The configure window does *both* of those thing for you.

Comment: Thanks John, that's exactly what I was looking for. I resolved it before you answered however, by completely deleting App Insights from my Bot Application, 'clean' and then closing the solution, before re-opening and created a new App Insights - not very elegant but it worked.